# Does Word 2013 support templates being linked to other templates?

Tags: microsoft-office-2013, templates

I would like to have one master template for items common to all of them and specific templates linked to it for specific documents. Can this be done?

The topic has been brought up [here](https://superuser.com/q/290971), but that was four years ago. Maybe something has changed?

Answer (score 0):

In **Word 2016**, there is a master `Normal` template that saves various settings (layout, spacing, etc.) you changed and made default. I assume this is where you start. And I'm certain for backward-compatibility this exists in 2013.